# How can I trigger a BroadcastReceiver on Android 11 using adb?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb, android-broadcast

I have two receivers I want to trigger manually and I can't seem to do it. These are the commands I'm using:

`adb -s deviceid shell am broadcast -a action android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`

or

`adb -s deviceid shell am broadcast -a action android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON`

I've tried adding `-p mypackage` or -n `mypackage/myreceiver` and they never get triggered. I also don't see anything on logcat. Adb returns `result=0`, not sure what that means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
adb -s deviceid shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.mypackage.broadcast/com.mypackage.broadcast.Broadcaster
```

Example of broadcast class.

```
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;

public final class Broadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override
    public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        intent.setClass(context, Starter.class);
        //Note: without this flag android will throw a runtime exception.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), 1) .show();
            forceStop();
        }
        forceStop();
    }
    
    private final void forceStop() {
        clearAbortBroadcast();
        //throw new RuntimeException();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
}
```

Starter.java //Class that you want to start

```
public final class Starter extends Activity {
     @Override
      protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Do something
      }
}
```

And dont forget to put this inside your manifest.

```
 <application
android:noHistory="true"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:exported="true"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        
<!-- RECEIVER -->
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.mypackage.broadcast.Broadcaster"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
```

Comment: This worked but with `-n` not `-p`. I'll mark it as correct, hopefully you'll edit it or others will see this comment.